# How to make multiple .setAttribute on a single element

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes

my code is

```
elem.setAttribute( 'style','background-color:' + l_DivBgcolor);
```

and i want also to add a border color same to the color of the bgcolor..
my problem is how do i add another style to the current style after setting a bgcolor?

i trien putting

```
elem.setAttribute( 'style','border-color:' + l_DivBgcolor  );
```

after the first setAttribute but it removes the bgcolor ang set the border color only..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use an attribute for this. Attributes are incorrectly implemented in IE and are almost never what you need. Also, assigning to the style attribute will wipe out existing inline styles, including those set by script. Use the universally-supported `style` property instead:

```
elem.style.backgroundColor = l_DivBgcolor;
elem.style.borderColor = l_DivBgcolor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with:

```
elem.setAttribute( 'style','border-color:' + l_DivBgcolor + '; background-color:' + l_DivBgcolor + ';');
```

Or you could try:

```
elem.style.display.borderColor = lDivBgcolor;
elem.style.display.backgroundColor = lDivBgcolor;
```

Comment: The first approach won't work in IE 6 or 7, or 8 in quirks mode, and will also wipe out existing inlines styles in other browsers. The second approach is the only sensible way to do it, except that you've got it wrong by inserting `display.`.

Comment: *nods* I'm not suggesting it's the way forward to use inline styling like that, simply taking the original code and tweaking it to fit the question asked, but you're entirely correct it's not the way to do it. The latter... well, it had been a while since I did that, and for some reason I thought it did need the display parent in there.... not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to (+=) or replace (=) inline style rules with style.cssText.

When appending, any properties that exist in the original style are replaced with the new values. 
New properties are added, and any in the original but not in the replacement are left as they are.

```
elem.style.cssText+=';background-color:'+ l_DivBgcolor+';border-color:'+l_DivBgcolor;
```

Comment: Why would you do that rather than just use the properties of the `style` object?

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate them :

```
elem.setAttribute( 'style','background-color:' + l_DivBgcolor + ';border-color:' + l_DivBgcolor + ';');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
elem.setAttribute( 'style','background-color:' + l_DivBgcolor+ ' border-color:' + l_DivBgcolor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable and hard code values:

```
element.setAttribute( 'style','top:' + t + '; left:' + l + '; width:' + w + '; height:' + h + ';');
element.setAttribute( 'style','top: 0; left: 0 ; right: 0; bottom: 0; opacity: 0.7;');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Object and set multiAttribute!
for Example if use  a tag and

```
let attGroup={
id:'demo',
class:'style',
href:'#'
};

for(let key in attGroup){
 elem.setAttribute(`${key}`,`${attGroup[key]}`);
}
```

```
<a id="demo" class="style" href="#">Link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are changing the style attribute and not the style properties of the element directly you can concatenate the styles in a string

```
var atValue = 'border-color:' + l_DivBgcolor + ';';
atValue += 'background-color:' + l_DivBgcolor + ';';

elem.setAttribute( 'style', atValue );
```